# Display list of shortcuts in Ubuntu 17.10 gnome

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, 17.10, shortcuts

How do i see list of shortcut keys in ubuntu 17.10 gnome? When I was using 17.04 unity, just pressing the super key for 2-3 seconds displayed the shortcuts list. Is there any similar feature in 17.10 gnome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't. An overview of keyboard shortcuts for gnome shell is maintained here: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/CheatSheet